# Error when filtering dates in .CSV file for Google Sheets through Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Until last week the script was working perfectly, but something happened that when trying to import the .CSV data it returns totally blank, I couldn't find where the fault is.

Note: The script filters date data to collect future data, current and past data is only collected from yesterday.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getMaxRows(), sh.getMaxColumns());
  rg.clear({contentsOnly:true});
  var url="https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches_latest.csv";
  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvA=Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var now=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate());
  var daysAgo=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()-1);
  var daysLater=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()+15);
  var values=csvA.filter(function(e, i) {
    if(i>0) {
      var tA=e[0].split('-');
      var temp=new Date(tA[0],tA[1],tA[2]);
      return temp.getTime() >= daysAgo.getTime() && temp.getTime()<=daysLater.getTime();
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that your `var daysAgo=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()-1);` is in the future not the past

Comment: In fact daysAgo is greater than daysLater so your filter will never work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works now:

The big problem was the index for e in this line `var tA=e[1].split('-');//modified`

and subtracting 1 from getMonth() in this line: `var temp=new 
Date(tA[0],tA[1]-1,tA[2]).valueOf();//modified`

```
function myFunction() {
  //removed unnecessary junk up here
  var url="https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches_latest.csv";
  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var csvA=Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var dt=new Date();
  var now=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  var daysAgo=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-1).valueOf();//modified
  var daysLater=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()+15).valueOf();//modified
  var values=csvA.filter(function(e, i) {
    if(i>0) {
      var tA=e[1].split('-');//modified
      var temp=new Date(tA[0],tA[1]-1,tA[2]).valueOf();//modified
      return temp>=daysAgo && temp<=daysLater;//modified
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(values)).setWidth(1200).setHeight(500), "Display Results");
}
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(values)), "Display Results");
}
```

Here's what it returned:

[["season","date","league_id","league","team1","team2","spi1","spi2","prob1","prob2","probtie","proj_score1","proj_score2","importance1","importance2","score1","score2","xg1","xg2","nsxg1","nsxg2","adj_score1","adj_score2"],["2020","2020-06-14","1874","Swedish Allsvenskan","IK Sirius","Djurgardens IF","22.74","48.83","0.1765","0.5836","0.2399","0.9","1.84","","","0","2","","","","","",""],["2019","2020-06-14","1846","German 2. Bundesliga","Karlsruher SC","VfB Stuttgart","29.35","49.81","0.2142","0.5365","0.2493","1.1","1.87","85.0","99.8","2","1","1.09","1.98","1.12","1.83","2.1","1.05"],["2019","2020-06-14","1846","German 2. Bundesliga","SV Darmstadt 98","Hannover 96","33.43","38.7","0.3588","0.3577","0.2835","1.36","1.36","0.1","0.0","3","2","0.57","1.7","0.67","1.65","3.15","2.1"],["2019","2020-06-14","1846","German 2. Bundesliga","FC St. Pauli","Erzgebirge Aue","29.9","26.51","0.4543","0.2549","0.2908","1.46","1.02","13.2","0.0","2","1","1.88","2.28","1.24","1.82","2.1","1.05"],["2019","2020-06-14","1869","Spanish Primera Division","Athletic Bilbao","Atletico Madrid","71.79","83.78","0.2302","0.4752","0.2946","0.82","1.31","4.4","86.5","1","1","0.41","1.26","0.75","0.76","1.05","1.05"],["2019","2020-06-14","1837","Danish SAS-Ligaen","AaB","FC Midtjylland","45.27","61.72","0.2291","0.5102","0.2607","0.99","1.61","0.0","37.4","0","2","","","","","",""],["2020","2020-06-14","1874","Swedish Allsvenskan","IFK Goteborg","IF Elfsborg","35.71","29.51","0.5019","0.2418","0.2563","1.69","1.1","7.9","11.1","0","1","","","","","",""],["2020","2020-06-14","1874","Swedish Allsvenskan","IFK Norrkoping","Kalmar FF","47.52","18.17","0.7781","0.0578","0.1641","2.26","0.45","","","2","1","","","","","",""],["2019","2020-06-14","1845","German Bundesliga","Mainz","FC

Actually I get a lot more but it's too much to post.

Comment: Mate... Unfortunately it keeps returning completely blank, before this model worked and I don't remember why I had to add +1 for it to work positively.

I tried to adjust the parameters indicated by you, even so the return is null.

Comment: Perhaps there is another issue beyond the date declarations.  I don't know I didn't test it.

Comment: if e[0] was a real date then this `var temp=new Date(tA[0],tA[1],tA[2]);` might should be this `var temp=new Date(tA[0],tA[1]-1,tA[2]);` since months go from 0 to 11 in the Date() object

Comment: Unfortunately the return is still null, when I import without any date editing, it delivers perfectly, but just add the question of days that returns null.

Comment: I added the image of the debugger to the question in order to facilitate the visualization

Comment: Try it again I just changed something

Comment: Sorry, I understood that you would like to look at the script debug. I got your comment wrong. I will test the new modifications!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216014/discussion-between-cooper-and-brondby-if).